# Converting regular bootstrap code into React Bootstrap styled component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I am following a tutorial where a person is teaching me how to write Bootstrap code. They created a top bar that goes across the entire browser width with the following code

CSS

```css
    .top-bar {
      background: #7aaec4;
      height: 2.8rem;
      padding: .5rem 0;
    }
    .topbar a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
```

HTML Code

```html
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-12 text-right">
          <p>
            <a href="tel:+18885555555">Call us at +1 (888) 555-5555</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The code above created the top bar which runs across the browser width and has a specific height as well.

Now I am trying to get the same behavior but with react-bootstrap and styled-components. So I wrote this code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    
    const Styles = styled.div`
      background: #7aaec4;
      height: 2.8rem;
      padding: .5rem 0;
      text-align: right;
    
      a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
      }; 
    `;
    
    export const TopBar = () => {return (
      <Container>
        <Styles>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
              <a href="tel:+18885555555">Call us at +1 (888) 555-5555</a>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Styles>
      </Container>
    )}
```

And then finally use my component as

```
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <TopBar />
      <div>Hello World</div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

I see that the topbar is not running across the browser screen. it looks like this

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't be the Styled component be outside the container and the row?

Comment: yes that did the trick. thanks!